# How to crop an image while changing screen size for Web Development

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to fit some images on my page. I've seen multiple websites where the images are cropped as the page size changes. This can be seen here on this page: https://www.cremedecornell.net (the front image has the outsides removed as the browser changes size). I'm new to coding and I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Thelarge image with the text on it is the image I'm trying to do this on. Can anyone help me with this problem? Let me know if you need any more information.

```js
// Navigation Bar Underline
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a.active-menu").removeClass("active-menu");
    $(this).addClass("active-menu");
 });
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}


.topnav {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }

 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:3px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
  .leftimage{
    width:70%;
    position:absolute;left:0%;
  }
  .bio{
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;right:0%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .rndface{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
  }
.topname{
  padding-top:3%;
}
.school{
  padding-bottom:.4%;
  padding-top:5%;
}
.interests{
  padding-bottom:.4%;
}
.location{
  padding-bottom:.4%;
}
.fa {
  padding-left:2%;
  padding-right:2%;
  padding-top:4%;
  padding-bottom:3%;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.fa-instagram {
  color: white;
}
.fa-linkedin {
  color: white;
}
.section1{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}
.HelloIm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>
    Change
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="active-menu" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#news">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="#contact">DontUse</a>
    <a class="link" href="about.html">About</a>
  </header>
  <div class='section1'>
    <img class= 'leftimage' src="https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/styles/lead_article_image/public/blogs/lead-images/engineering_imagery.jpg" alt="ADDALT">
    <div class='HelloIm'>Hello I'm</div>>
  </div>
  <div class='bio'>
      <img class = 'rndface' src="https://www.topuniversities.com/sites/default/files/styles/lead_article_image/public/blogs/lead-images/engineering_imagery.jpg" alt="ADDALT">
      <p class='topname'>
        <h1>Rn</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
      </p>
      <p class='school'>
        New Trier High School
      </p>
      <p class='interests'>
        Engineering & Computer Science
      </p>
      <p class='location'>
        Chicago, Illinois
      </p>
      <p>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/rkin-a3a9541a5/" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.instagram.com/rn/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not cropped. The overflow is hidden. Look at this property (overflow) in css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to look into the css property `object-fit`. When setting it to `cover`, the image will be scaled up to fill its container, which crops the image if necessary.

```css
body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/2000/1000" />
```